# Overriding css variable on pseudoelement does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of creating a background pattern on my webpage using CSS variables and pseudo-elements. I've defined a CSS variable called `--rotation` that I am trying to use to alter the rotation of the pattern in the `body::before` pseudo-element. The `--rotation` variable should override the default value of 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

    :root {
      --line-pattern: repeating-linear-gradient(var(--rotation, 0),#DC6638, #DC6638 20px, #0D1335 20px, #0D1335 40px);
    }

    body {
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      background: var(--line-pattern);
    }
  
    body::before {
      --rotation:30deg;
      content: "";
      background: var(--line-pattern);
      position: absolute;
      inset: 100px;      
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Despite setting `--rotation` to 30deg in `body::before`, it doesn't seem to affect the pattern's rotation. Instead, the pattern remains identical to the body's background, with no visible rotation. I was expecting the pattern to rotate 30 degrees.

Could anyone help explain why `--rotation` isn't affecting the `body::before` pseudo-element as I expected? Any insights on how I can make the rotation work would be greatly appreciated.